# Open NativeScript project in Android Studio

Tags: nativescript, angular-nativescript

I have a robust app, created with NativeScript + Angular.
I would like to drop NativeScript and be able to continue working on the project in Android Studio.

We need to stop the development with NativeScript, without starting the app from scratch. Is this possible?

I've been trying to Google for it, but the docs are disappeared every link shows up 404.

Comment: As new NS8 come out there is also new documentation.  https://docs.nativescript.org/ and as stated just at start old are moved: https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/ . All search agents still didn't index it properly, but all (page not found)  is at old V.7

Comment: That's what I call unprofessional... and that's why we decided to drop NS. It was 2 years of struggle. BTW the doc 8 is like 50% ready...